# JLS violations via Number and custom types for switch selector expression

Tags: java, compiler-errors, autoboxing, jls

[JLS 17](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11) mentions for the `switch` selector expression (like the JLS' before it)

> The type of the selector expression must be char, byte, short, int, Character, Byte, Short, Integer, String, or an enum type (§8.9), or a compile-time error occurs.

Yet, this compiles (and works)

```java
public class rough2 {
    class f{
        public static void sop(Object o){System.out.println(o);}
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Number no = 10.23f;
        switch (no) {
            case Integer i -> f.sop("%d is integer".formatted(i));
            case Float fl -> f.sop("%3.2f is float".formatted(fl));
            default -> f.sop("don't know about "+no);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, `Number` isn't one of the listed types.

1. Why is there no compilation error?

Interestingly, `no.getClass()` gives `java.lang.Float`. Is generic autoboxing a thing?

Even more bizarrely (and maybe this should be a separate question - if so tell me), replacing the above main method with the one below still works.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        class a {}
        class b extends a {}
        a obj = new a();//new b();
        switch (obj) {
            case b typeB -> f.sop("is sub type b");
            case a typeA -> f.sop("is a");
        }
    }
```

2. How is *this* not a JLS violation?

---

Please note that you may need to `--enable-preview` features in JDK 17 to run the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific syntax you show is defined in [JEP 406: Pattern Matching for switch (Preview)](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/406), and is a preview feature. Preview features are not defined in the JLS itself, but instead are defined separately, as mentioned in JSL 17 [section 1.5. Preview Features](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-1.html#jls-1.5):

> Preview language features are specified in standalone documents that
> indicate changes ("diffs") to *The Java® Language Specification* for
> that release. The specifications of preview language features are
> incorporated into *The Java® Language Specification* by reference, and
> made a part thereof, if and only if preview features are enabled at
> compile time.
>
> Java SE 17 defines one preview language feature: *Pattern Matching for
> `switch`*. The standalone document which specifies this preview
> feature is available at the Oracle web site which hosts *The Java®
> Language Specification*: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/.

This 'diff' document of JLS 17 for the preview feature is [Pattern Matching for switch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/preview/specs/patterns-switch-jls.html). It 'applies' when you specify `--enable-preview`. Among others, it removes the line you quote in your question:

> <s>The type of the selector expression must be char, byte, short, int,
> Character, Byte, Short, Integer, String, or an enum type (8.9), or a
> compile-time error occurs.</s>

As to your question *"Why is there no compilation error?"*, because that is how this feature works. You provide a `Number`, and then check whether it is an `Integer` or a `Float`, or otherwise apply a default, both `Integer` and `Float` are subclasses of `Number`. I recommend reading [JEP 406](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/406) for more details.

As to *"Is generic autoboxing a thing?"*, there are no generics involved here. You assign a `float` literal to a variable of an object type, so it is autoboxed to `Float`, and given `Number` is a superclass of `Float`, the assignment is valid.

I'm not sure what you mean with the *"Even more bizarrely"* part, or why you think it is *bizarre*, but again: read [JEP 406](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/406) for more details.

Comment: in one word 'JEP 406' (or may be two)..................I get it ..that strike through on the so far staple switch definition is as clarifying as a lightning bolt....regarding that "generic autoboxing" I meant that most of the time autobox is from `float` to `Float` or the like but here its from `float` to `Float` then to its supertype...that's what threw me off but I realised what was happening afterwards (exactly as you explained)

Comment: JEP 406: *"A pattern variable introduced by a switch label is definitely matched in the associated switch rule expression, switch rule block or switch rule throw statement."* -- does this mean pattern matched switch needs to be compulsorily exhaustive regardless of whether it's used as a statement or an expression?

Comment: @lineage I suggest you ask a new question for that